# mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access or execute an executable with C

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I created a clustering program using MPI using 4 nodes. But when I run the MPI program, I can't execute the program even though I've been given full access to the folder I created.

The program I made to count the number of processors running from each node/client

```
   #include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    printf("hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",processor_name,world_rank,world_size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

but when I run the program with the command :  `mpirun -np 8 --hostfile /mnt/sharedfolder/hostfile /mnt/sharedfolder/hello_world.out`

a message like this appears

```
    mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access
or execute an executable:

Executable: /mnt/sharedfolder/hello_world.out
Node: node-02

while attempting to start process rank 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
8 total processes failed to start
```

previously I have given full access to the firewall on the google cloud platform on each node.please help me, I'm still learning

Comment: Try `mpirun -np 8 --hostfile /mnt/sharedfolder/hostfile ls -l /mnt/sharedfolder/hello_world.out` to confirm the binary is available and with the right permissions on all your nodes.

Comment: I've tried it and it can't access the hello_world.out program. How to grant access to a file?

Comment: you would typically have `/mnt/sharedfolder` on a shared filesystem (such as NFS or Lustre) mounted on all the nodes.

Comment: It's kinda perverse to name something `/mnt/sharedfolder` if it's not actually mounted as shared. Are you sure that directory is available and shared everywhere?

Comment: I have given access to all nodes in the `mnt/sharedfolder` folder with the command `chmod 7777 -R sharedfolder` and I have tried this by creating a file and it can be accessed by all nodes. But I still can't execute the file `hello_world.mpi`